# PowerModeChanged triggers late

Tags: c#, .net, windows

My application needs to resume operations after the system wakes up after sleep. To do that, the app registers a PowerModeChanged event listener, waiting for PowerMode.Resume, where some bookkeeping needs to be done.

This code worked quite well with Windows 7, but with Windows 10 the PowerModeChanged does not fire until a key is pressed or mouse is moved.

```
    public Shell()
    {
        Logging.LogMethodEntry();

        try
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += new PowerModeChangedEventHandler(SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Logging.LogException(exc);
        }

        Logging.LogMethodExit();
    }

    private void SystemEvents_PowerModeChanged(object sender, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Logging.LogMethodEntry(sender, e);

        try
        {
            switch (e.Mode)
            {
                case PowerModes.StatusChange
                case PowerModes.Resume:
                    Logging.LogInfo("Resuming...");
                    // some code here

                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Logging.LogException(exc);
        }

        Logging.LogMethodExit();
    }
```

I could not find any hint about any changes that were introduced in this mechanics for Windows 10, but maybe there is some settings I'm just not aware of...

Comment: It is not obvious from the question what you did to get the system to resume operating.   Using the mouse or keyboard will do it.

Comment: Oh, right! My bad. The system is resumed by a Task defined in the Task Scheduler. The task just starts a self-closing cmd.exe, as it only has to resume the system at a given time. Other components are designed to proceed from there on their own.
So, the system resumes, but everything stays still until the mouse or keyboard is poked.
It seems, that the hint from @Damien_The_Unbeliever might do the trick. Have to tweak my code a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PowerModeChanged event relies upon the [WM_POWERBROADCAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/wm-powerbroadcast) windows event. We note from the documentation for that event that there are two different resume events - `PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC` and `PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND`.

We can see from the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/win32/SystemEvents.cs,898) that .NET only looks for the second of these events, not the first, and the second is defined only to fire

> if the resume is triggered by user input, such as pressing a key.

Which appears to match your experience. You may wish to put your own message handler in place to watch for the first event. But [note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/pbt-apmresumeautomatic) -

> In Windows 10, version 1507 systems or later, if the system is resuming from sleep only to immediately enter hibernation, this event is not delivered. A WM_POWERBROADCAST message is not sent in this case.